# Mixing data from two csv files with date field

Tags: bash, csv

I have two csv files.

File1.csv

```
F1    F2
14:01 22
14:05 23
14:07 34
14:58 98
15:01 22
15:10 24
```

File2.csv

```
F1    F2
14:01 22
14:06 21
14:07 34
14:59 08
15:01 22
15:19 20
```

And is it possible to have something like below ?

```
F1    F2   F3 
14:01 22   22
14:05 23
14:06      21
14:07 34   34
14:58 98
14:59      08
15:01 22   22
15:10 24
15:19      20
```

Thank you.

Comment: you can use `awk` for this

Comment: `15:10 24` instead of `15:10 46` in expected output, and `15:01 44` instead of `15:01 22`

Comment: @Ten-Coin your edit should go in another post question because you are asking something different now

Comment: @ballangddang I have edited my question , Please check

Comment: _Note: You can use any programming language._ What? Is this an assignment you give to us? If so, I am voting to close the question since this is not how [so] works.

Comment: Why is my answer down-voted? OP just edited the title to have a new requirement

Comment: @fedorqui till now there is a discussion about bash & awk , so to clear that I mentioned that note but I didnt mean to say like a task.

Comment: Still, you should show your efforts as described in [ask].

Comment: Dear @Inian, I appreciate your work, however, Why? the question should have been closed instead of answered if OP doesn't edit your mistakes (main); In my case, down voted when you edited the question and added the `awk` tag ..... I hope you understand me

Comment: @Ten-Coin: You cannot have a pure `bash` solution for this. None of them will attempt doing it

Comment: @Inian I just did and also I didn't down-vote your answer, why did you remove your solution ?

Comment: @JoseRicardoBustosM.: I just don't get it, When the OP asks for solution( with an expectation of a reliable, efficient, portable and fast running), they knowingly or unknowingly add a tag (`bash` in this case) expecting it will solve their problem, but few experience people like us should know, `bash` doesn't scale for such input, and even if it works, will not for huge files. That's why added the tag `awk` to let know the OP the best way to solve the problem

Comment: @ballangddang: Carefully read and understand this, http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/169716/why-is-using-a-shell-loop-to-process-text-considered-bad-practice, @Ed Morton, the leading expert on `awk` here in SO, always emphasizes on this to avoid bash for processing text for the exact reason I mentioned.

Comment: @Inian I completely agree with you, though in my opinion OP asking such a -basic- question adding the `bash` tag also will expect to see a pure and native bash answer so they can learn the mechanism behind the language, if you just throw a solution without the base how do you expect the man fishing, just providing him with a fish ?

Comment: @ballangddang: On a lighter note, do you expect OP to comprehend your answer? :D if he wants to _learn the language_? I bet he can't.

Comment: @Inian Certainly not at first sight but if he learns the basis of Bash semantic he will quickly be able to read what my script do, but was he supposed to comprehend what was behind the wheel with your awk answer, neither did i?

Comment: @ballangddang: _peace_

Comment: @Inian You did not understand me, my problem is not in the use of `awk`, even, I proposed it in the first comment .....

Comment: @Inian more info [here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/299353/penalty-for-answering-help-vampire-questions-or-reward-closure)

Comment: A little nitpick: `File1.csv` and `File1.csv` are _not_ CSV files, as CSV (Comma Separated Values) files separate fields with commas. What you have are just text files whose fields occupy fixed number of positions in each line.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a pure `bash` solution, not the most efficient as pointed by @Inian but still **pure**

```
#!/bin/bash

f1=()
f2=()

while read -r f1l; do
    f1[${#f1[@]}]="$f1l"
done < File1.csv
while read -r f2l; do
    f2[${#f2[@]}]="$f2l"
done < File2.csv

output=$'F1\tF2\n'
for (( i=1; i<${#f1[@]}; ++i ))
do
    f1c1=${f1[i]%% *}
    f1c2=${f1[i]##* }
    f2c1=${f2[i]%% *}
    f2c2=${f2[i]##* }

    if [[ $f1c1 = $f2c1 ]]; then
        output+="$f1c1"$'\t'$(($f1c2+$f2c2))$'\n'
    else
        output+="$f1c1"$'\t'"$f1c2"$'\n'
        output+="$f2c1"$'\t'"$f2c2"$'\n'
    fi
done

echo "${output:0:-1}" > File3.csv
```